# Запомнить точку выполнения метода и продолжить работу с неё

Tags: c#

```
    public interface IService 
    {
    bool Process(Info info, SshTunnel ssh);
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {

       public bool Process(Info info, SshTunnel ssh)
       {
         var personalInfo = new GetPersonalInfo(ssh);

         if (personalInfo == null) return false;

         var totalPoints = GetTotalPoints(ssh);

         if (personalInfo == null) return false;

         return true;
       }

       private SomeInfo GetPersonalInfo(SshTunnel ssh)
       {
         //Example
         try
         {
            //Get personal info
         }
         catch(NetworkException ex)
         {

         }

         return new SomeInfo();
        }

       private SomeInfo GetTotalPoints(SshTunnel ssh)
       {
         //Example
         try
         {
            //Get total points
         }
         catch (NetworkException ex)
         {
            //
         }

         return new SomeInfo();
        }
}
```

Есть 2 варианта работы данного класса если в каком-то из методов GetTotalPoints или GetPersonalInfo упал ssh:

- Сразу же заменить его на новый и продолжить работу (С того метода, в котором он упал, что бы не запрашивать заново уже полученные данные. Например если ssh перестал работать в GetTotalPoints, а GetPersonalInfo успешно получил данные)
- Получить новый ssh и запрашивать данные через него с самого начала, даже если один из методов успешно получил данные.

Проблема следующая.. В случае, когда мне нужно получить новый туннель и начать выполнение метода Process с самого начала, без сохранения прогресса, я просто возвращаю false, получаю новый туннель и запускаю данный метод заново. А вот как сделать второй случай, когда мне не нужно начинать выполнение заново, а именно с того места, в котором туннель упал, что бы не запрашивать уже полученные данные заново, я не понимаю как!

Класс, который это всё запускает

```
public class Processer
{
    private IService service;
    private InfoSource infoSource;
    private SshList sshList;

    public Processer(IService _service)
    {
        service = _service;
        infoSource = Map.GetInfoSource();
        sshList = Map.GetSSHList();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Случай, когда нужно выполнить метод без сохранения прогресса (с начала)
        bool IsPassed;
        var info = infoSource.Take();

        do
        {
            var ssh = sshList.Take();
            IsPassed = service.Process(info, ssh);

        } while (!IsPassed);
    }
}
```

Comment: personalInfo и totalPoints у вас же где-то сохраняются? Не вхолостую же они работают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать простенький конечный автомат. Ваш класс может выглядеть так, и вы сможете добавлять новые шаги, если понадобиться:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private enum State
    {
        Begin,
        GetPersonalInfo,
        GetTotalPoints,
        End
    }

    private State _state = State.Begin;

    public bool Process(Info info, SshTunnel ssh)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            switch (_state)
            {
                case State.Begin:
                    _state = State.GetPersonalInfo;
                    break;

                case State.GetPersonalInfo:
                    var personalInfo = GetPersonalInfo(ssh);
                    if (personalInfo == null)
                        return false;
                    else
                        _state = State.GetTotalPoints;
                    break;

                case State.GetTotalPoints:
                    var totalPoints = GetTotalPoints(ssh);
                    if (totalPoints == null)
                        return false;
                    else
                        _state = State.End;
                    break;

                case State.End:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Так как компилятор сам умеет строить такие автоматы (для асинхронных методов, или для методов использующих `yield`), то можно поручить эту работу ему. Пример:

```
public interface IService { }
public class Info { }
public class SshTunnel { }

public class Service : IService
{
    private SshTunnel _ssh;
    private IEnumerator<bool> _proccessStateMachine;

    public bool Process(Info info, SshTunnel ssh)
    {
        _ssh = ssh;

        if (_proccessStateMachine == null) // извлекаем IEnumerator
            _proccessStateMachine = ProcessInternal().GetEnumerator();

        _proccessStateMachine.MoveNext();
        return _proccessStateMachine.Current;
    }

    private IEnumerable<bool> ProcessInternal()
    {
        // код выглядит как обычный, только с yield
        while (true)
        {
            var personalInfo = GetPersonalInfo(_ssh);
            if (personalInfo == null)
                yield return false;
            else
                break;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            var totalPoints = GetTotalPoints(_ssh);
            if (totalPoints == null)
                yield return false;
            else
                break;
        }

        yield return true;
    }

    // эмуляция нестабильной работы

    private int counter;

    private object GetPersonalInfo(SshTunnel ssh)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetPersonalInfo");
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        if (++counter % 5 == 0)
            return new object();
        return null;
    }

    private object GetTotalPoints(SshTunnel ssh)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetTotalPoints");
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        if (++counter % 5 == 0)
            return new object();
        return null;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = new Service();
        while (!service.Process(null, null))
            ;
    }
}
```